# iOS 5 Newsstandkit where does it store downloaded issues?

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios5

I'm trying to figure out more about iOS 5 newsstand kit and where it stores the downloaded issues, I have read the documentation and can see that there is an NKLibrary class but cannot see any indication on how to handle the downloads or where they are actually stored.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, so NewstandKit works a little differently than you might expect. Take a look at this for the nitty gritty: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/StoreKit/Reference/NewsstandKit_Framework/_index.html

But, Basically during the issue download the app should be passing its (the product's) information including it's NSURL an NKIssue via [NKIssue addAssetWithRequest]. Assuming the download doesn't fail and you have done the other Newstand stuff right, the product should be saved in the properly and you do not have to worry about dictating a specific location for it to be saved.

Another reason to not worry too much about where the issues are being saved, is that Newstand will delete old issues if the device's storage becomes limited.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, this sounds like it confirms what I thought that the Issues are stored elsewhere on the device which iOS manage perhaps similar to the cache folders but it is excluded from iCloud Backups.

Answer (score 1):

Never worrying about the downloads's destination might not be the best way to deal with the problem. It's true that the destination is chosen automatically when downloading an asset. However, what's saved then is just a temporary file, which must be moved somewhere else and which might also need to be processed in whatever way.

Take a look at the "contentURL" property in NKIssue. This is the location which NewsstandKit recommends as the very destination of issue-related assets.

Cheers :)